# How do I use this variable in a non Powershell Command in a Powershell Script?

Tags: powershell

How do i prevent the "Employee" text becoming part of the $number variable and get the string to work.
It's a non powershell command I'm trying to run in a Powershell script.

```
$firstname = "John"
$Lastname = "Smith"
$Number = "7"

gam update group "Office$NumberEmployee" add member user "$Firstname.$Lastname@email.com"
```

Answer (score 1):

Use braces to demarcate boundaries of a variable within a powershell script.
Example below:

```
  gam update group "Office${Number}Employee" add member user "${Firstname}.${Lastname}@email.com"
```

Comment: I tried that but it seems to remove the variable.

I got this error 

gam : Group: OfficeEmployee@email.com, Does not exist

Answer (score 0):

You can use single quotes or the escape character in PowerShell to prevent it from trying to expand the string following your `$` (dollar sign).

The most common is to just use single quotes for the string...but it is not really best practice to use one over the other that I'm aware of, purely preference. I think as long as you use one method among all your scripts is sufficient.

Examples (with screenshot):

```
"Office$NumberEmployee"
'Office$NumberEmployee'
"Office`$NumberEmployee"
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround by just creating the variable.

```
$firstname = "John"
$Lastname = "Smith"
$Number = "7"
$NumberEmployee = $Number + "Employee"

gam update group "Office$NumberEmployee" add member user "$Firstname.$Lastname@email.com"
```